# Seleccionar datos de celdas de una columna con jquery

Tags: jquery, html5

tengo la siguiente tabla

```
<table class="table table-hover table-secondary mt-1 table-responsive">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Producto</th>
             <th>Cantidad</th>
             <th>Sub Total Efectivo</th>
             <th>Sub Total Tarjeta</th>
         </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="CarroDeCompra">
         <tr>
             <td>Nombre</td>
             <td>Cantidad</td>
             <td>Efectivo</td>
             <td>Tarjeta</td>                                       
         </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

Lo que deseo es contar las cantidades de la segunda columna, la que dice cantidad.

Busqué en Internet y encontré este código, pero no estaría funcionando:

```
function ContarProductos() {
    let cantidad =0;
    ('#CarroDeCompra td').find('td:eq(1)').each(function() {

    //obtenemos el valor de la celda
    valor = $(this).html();

    //sumamos, recordar parsear, si no se concatenara.
    cantidad += parseInt(valor)
    });

    return cantidad;
}
```

¿Alguno me puede dar un consejo? Muchas Gracias desde ya!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar esta función:

```
function contar(columna){
    let cantidad = 0;
    $('#CarroDeCompra').find('td:nth-child('+columna+')').each(function(){
        cantidad += +($(this).text());
    });
    return cantidad;
}

contar(2); // Contamos todos los valores de la segunda columna.
```

Para seleccionar la columna n usamos `:nth-child(n)` en este caso n es 2, ya que la columna que queremos sumar es la segunda.
Luego, y suponiendo que sólo tienes número enteros en dicha columna, puedes usar `+valor` para transformar un valor a un entero.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba:

```
$('#CarroDeCompra').find('td:eq(1)').each(function(){
```

*Sin el `td`*

Comment: recuerda que siempre debes explicar tu código, no solo poner el script

Comment: hola @shadow, gracias por el consejo del comentario, prometo hacerlo de ahora en mas... le quite el td y me dice esto "#CarroDeCompra".find is not a function

Comment: perdon el codigo quedo asi :('#CarroDeCompra').find('td:eq(1)').each(function(){

        //obtenemos el valor de la celda
        valor = $(this).html();
        
        //sumamos, recordar parsear, si no se concatenara.
        cantidad += parseInt(valor)
    });

Comment: @Alex, puedes hacerlo en esta misma respuesta. La idea es que la puedes perfeccionar. Dale al botón editar y agrega el detalle que le falta a la respuesta.